# Is there an elegant way to track multiple domains under seperate accounts with google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, multiple-domains

I have a situation where a content management system uses the same template for multiple websites with different domain names and I can't make a separate template for each. However, each website needs to be tracked separately with google analytics. Would this be appropriate to track each domain like this by putting in some conditional code? And would this be robust enough not to break? Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  switch (location.hostname){
    case 'www.aaa.com':
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1']);
        break;
    case 'www.bbb.com':
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-2']);
        break;
    case 'www.ccc.com':
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-3']);
        break;
  }

  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
  })();

</script>
```

Just to be clear, each website is a separate domain name and must be tracked separately, NOT different domains with same pages on one analytics profile.

Comment: Can you modify the template to add the `switch` server-side? This way you'd always output the proper javascript code for the domain the user is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing in a map of ids allows you to remove the ugly `switch`

```
var ids = {
    'www.aaa.com': 'UA-xxxxxxx-1',
    'www.bbb.com': 'UA-xxxxxxx-2'
}
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', ids[location.hostname]])
```

Comment: nice! I should have thought of that.